# Print A User Specified Amount of Word Documents In Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, printing, ms-word, office-interop

Hi there i am looking to use the print dialog box when printing from my VB program. I am trying to print Word Documents, i can successfully print one document, however if i specify more than one document in print dialog box then the printer will still only print one. All i need is to be able to choose how many documents i want to print.
Thanks

Below is my code for the relevant button:

```
Private Sub Button19_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button19.Click
    Dim f As New OpenFileDialog
    Dim p As New PrintDialog
    Dim app As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document

    'Open file and print dialogs to get desired document and printer
    If p.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        'Create instance of Word Application
        app = New Word.Application

        'Set Printer
        app.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup(Printer:=p.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1)

        'Set filename to object type
        Dim filename As Object = f.FileName
        Dim m As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        'Open document
        doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\CamJam\Tickets\Monday\drivingrange_mon_pm.docx")

        'Print document
        app.PrintOut()

        'Close document
        app.Documents.Close()

        'Quit word application
        app.Quit()

        'Release 
        app = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: loop thru the documents the user selected rather than printing a hardcoded file

Comment: Are you trying to print several different documents, or multiple copies of the same document? For different documents, you'll need to loop through the documents as mentioned by @Plutonix. For multiple copies of the same document, set the Copies parameter when calling PrintOut (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840681.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have come across something else now however, i need to declare "Printer" in this statement; "printer.Copies = printDlg.Copies" however i do not know what to declare it as, i have already declared printdlg with the following, "Dim printDlg As PrinterDlg
  printDlg = New PrinterDlg" but am not sure how to declare Printer

Comment: Yes i need to print a specified amount which will be stated in the print dialog box

Comment: All i need to do now is declare "printer" however i do not know what to declare it as